# Saving apex param value to apex controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

We have a visualforce presenting a list of dates. It uses a repeater to display the dates to a user and I have been trying to add a button to the repeater that then saves the value to the controller to update the record.  It is a detail page visualforce page.

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:page standardController="Order" extensions="customOrderExtenstionTest" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" >
 <apex:form>
    <apex:actionregion>
         <apex:repeat value="{!list}" var="currentDate">
            <apex:outputText value="{0,date, EEEE dd MMMM yy}">
                <apex:param value="{!currentDate}"/>    
            </apex:outputText>
            <apex:commandLink  style="btn" action="{!saveDate}" value="Select Date" reRender="hidden"> {!currentDate}
               <apex:param name="selectedDate" id="param1" value="{!currentDate}" assignTo="{!selectedDate}"/>
            </apex:commandLink>
            <apex:outputPanel id="hidden" rendered="false"/>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:actionregion>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

And the apex is pretty simple:

**Apex Custom Controller**

```
public with sharing class BulkyItemOrderCalendarController 
public Date selectedDate {get;set;}
...
public pageReference saveDate(){
    try{
        system.debug('SELECTED DATE ============' + selectedDate);
        currOrder.Allocated_Date__c = selectedDate;
        update currOrder;
        return null;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('Exception occurred '+String.valueOf(e));
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

An error is always displayed stating "Argument cannot be null". However I can see the content of {!currentDate} printed on the VF page.  I am aware of the commandButton issue so I have tried commandLink without success (above) but I also tried the rerender of a hidden panel hack too.

Thanks, sorry I fear it is another obvious mistake/misunderstanding.

Comment: I think you have to add the `name` attribute to your `<apex:param>` tag for it to actually bind back to the controller. Can't hunt down where I read that at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, I added a name attribute in (I edited the code above) but I am afraid the same thing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes as Adrian mentioned in comment Name works as a key so you need to add that as well. Without it you don't get any error but your value will not be passed to controller.

[Apex:param](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_param.htm)

Also Date type can't be directly passed as Apex:param only support string, number, or boolean value. So you need to convert it into string pass it into controller and then in controller change it into date again.

```
<apex:param name="setDescription" value="{!TEXT(date2)}" assignTo="{!dateString}" />
```

Comment: Thanks that is much better.  Thanks.  I can see the date being passed and in the debug it is format as yyyy-mm-dd yet I am receiving an error stating: "Exception occurred System.TypeException: Invalid date: 2017-10-27"  I used "date.parse(selectedDate);"

Comment: got it working with  date.valueOf(selectedDate); thanks.